# jQuery - find all IDs in a class

Tags: jquery, class

Let's say i have a html table like this:

```
<table>
<tr id="a" class="red"><td>test</td></tr>
<tr id="b" class="red"><td>test</td></tr>
<tr id="c" class="red"><td>test</td></tr>
<tr id="d" class="red"><td>test</td></tr>
<tr id="e" class="green"><td>test</td></tr>
<tr id="f" class="blue"><td>test</td></tr>
</table>
```

How can i loop through/get all ids of class "red" using jQuery?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use [**.each()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
var idArray = [];
$('.red').each(function () {
    idArray.push(this.id);
});
```

Comment: Three answers in one minute and every one is working. Thanks! I mark this one, cause in the end i decided to use this one. So sad i can't mark all of them...

Comment: or

var idArray = [];
$('.red').each(function () {
    idArray.push($(this).attr('id'));
});

Answer (score 10):

You can do this using the [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method like:

```
var ids = $('.red').map(function () {
    return this.id;
}).get().join();

console.log(ids);  // Result: a,b,c,d
```

---

**Explanation:-**

- Here the below code:-

  ```
  $('.red').map(function () {
      return this.id;
  })
  ```

  we are passing each element in the current matched set `.red` through a function, producing a new jQuery object containing the return values, which is the `id` of the each element.
   So, the above code results in a new jQuery object like:

  ```
  ["a", "b", "c", "d", prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[4], context: document]
  ```
- Next, [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) is used to retrieve the DOM elements matched by the new jQuery object above. So, after using `.get()` our result is like:

  ```
  ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
  ```
- Next, [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method joins all elements of an array (which we got after using `.get()`) into a string like:

  ```
  a,b,c,d
  ```

  If we use `.join(', ')` we can get some space after comma like:

  ```
  a, b, c, d
  ```

  or a `.join('~')` would result in:

  ```
  a~b~c~d
  ```

  You can always modify the separator in the `.join()` based on your requirement.
- ```js
  var ids = $('.red').map(function() {
    return this.id;
  }).get().join();

  console.log(ids); // Result: a,b,c,d
  ```

  ```css
  .red{color:red;}
  .green{color:green;}
  .blue{color:blue;}
  ```

  ```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <table>
    <tr id="a" class="red"><td>test</td></tr>
    <tr id="b" class="red"><td>test</td></tr>
    <tr id="c" class="red"><td>test</td></tr>
    <tr id="d" class="red"><td>test</td></tr>
    <tr id="e" class="green"><td>test</td></tr>
    <tr id="f" class="blue"><td>test</td></tr>
  </table>
  ```

Answer (score 8):

Using [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) as easy as

```
//ids is an array of the element ids with class red
var ids = $('table .red').map(function(){
    return this.id
}).get()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Mefg5/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.red').each(function(){
    confirm(this.id);
});
```